# Old Crystal Reports doesn't like Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, vb6, crystal-reports

About 15 years ago I wrote a system for a client in VB6 using Crystal Reports.  They've been happily using the system, until they contacted me a week or two ago.  Apparently they decided to get with the 21st century and upgrade their computers to Windows 7 x64.  Now the VB6 system still works fine, but the Crystal Reports have gone all pear shaped.  Ferinstance, they cannot "Preview" reports anymore - they get an error message:

> Error in File C:\Program Files (x86)\Blahblahblah System\MyReport.rpt: Invalid collation value.

Googled that message; it has never before been reported so far as I can tell.  But printing works fine... except on one or two computers on their network, where any attempt to print a report is met with the error:

> Error in File C:\Program Files (x86)\Blahblahblah System\MyReport.rpt: No default printer.

Needless to say, the computer *does* have a default printer, so that message is clearly bogus.

They do have the original VB6 source code, but that's not much good to me, since I no longer have a VB6 development environment.  I could use it just to read it and maybe diagnose...

Anyone have any ideas about old Crystal Reports files, and what might cause the error messages above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, it's just good old DLL Hell.  Found 3 different versions of `CRPE32.DLL` on one computer.  By playing around with putting different DLLs into `c:\windows\syswow64` I found one that worked.  Mostly.